# como expandir ou diminuir a altura de uma imagem no html e css

Tags: html, css3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá boa tarde a todos,gostaria de saber como eu expando a imagem de cima ate ela atingir toda essa parte branca sem deixar a parte da esquerda em branco e tmb gostaria de saber como diminuir a altura da imagem abaixo.

Comment: Amigo sem o código fica difícil te responder. Tente colocar width:100% nas imagens ou poste o código para te darmos uma resposta precisa

Answer (score 0):

## Propriedades width e height

Para ajustar larguras e alturas, você pode utilizar as propriedades CSS width e height. Além do mais, você pode escolher o valor e unidade que quiser. (px, cm, in, % e etc)

### Exemplo

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
```

## Seu caso

Você não compartilhou seu código HTML ou CSS. Por isso, vou usar as seguintes classes: .*img-bola* e .*img-botao-escroto*. Então, basta seguir os passos:

1. Colocar a classe .*img-bola*, na primeira tag ;
2. Colocar a classe .*img-botao-escroto*, na segunda tag ;
3. Criar uma regra CSS referente a .*img-bola*, usando `width: 100%;`;
4. Criar uma regra CSS referente a .*img-botao-escroto*, usando `height: <altura desejada>;`;

### Resultado

```css
.img-bola {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-botao-escroto {
  height: <escolha a altura>:
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/KoyP4pY.jpg" class="img-bola">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/9q7DJjq.jpg" class="img-botao-escroto">
```

**Aqui vai um link, pra tu estudar sobre o assunto:**

http://www.htmlprogressivo.net/2014/04/Propriedades-width-height-Como-Definir-Altura-Largura-em-CSS-Tutorial.html